# Check for exact match in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, anagram

I built an anagram solver in Python 2.7 which takes an input, finds all permutations of it, and then checks if it matches any of the word in [this dictionary text file](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt). It works pretty well, but it has one problem. It doesn't only give exact matches, it gives a match where the anagram is only part of a word in the text file.

Example:

> Input scrambled word: python
>
> Possible Word: ypnoth
>
> Possible Word: python
>
> Possible Word: hypnot

It does this because there are some words like hypnotist or hypnotic which contain hypnot. It's still easy to solve the anagram with this bug, but I want the program to be as easy as possible.

```
# import permutations module
from itertools import permutations as prm

# take input
scrambled_word = list(str(raw_input("Input scrambled word: ")))

# empty lists that will be appended to later
prm_list = []
possible_words = []

# takes each permutation of the input and puts in a list
for i in prm(scrambled_word):
   prm_list.append("".join(i))

def check(x, y):

   # open list of words
   dictionary = file('E:\MRP\Text_Files\dictionary.txt')

      # check each line in the dictionary against each item
      # in the list of permutations and add it to another empty list if it's a match
   for line in dictionary:
      for i in x:
         if i in line:
            y.append(i)


check(prm_list, possible_words)

# delete duplicates
possible_words = list(set(possible_words))

# print out possible words
for i in possible_words:
   print "Possible Word: " + i
```

How could I only print out exact matches when comparing the permutations and the dictionary? I've tried the `==` operator in the `check` function, but that made the program worse.

Comment: `==` should work. If it is not working for exact matches, maybe there could be some whitespace char when you are extracting from file. Try out `line.strip()` before you compare it with anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of that you check witht `in` operation (`if i in line`) you need to check with `==`
but as line has a `\n` at the trailing you need to add one `\n` at the end of your words.

```
if i+'\n' == line
```

Comment: @michaelpri you're welcome . if you want to get rid of new line you can read your file with `splitlines`

Comment: @michaelpri with that, it should print "doghouse" when you enter "houes".